# What throwable can't be caught?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, devise

The following code in my Ruby on Rails application:

```
def test
    begin
        puts 'a'
        authenticate_user!
        puts 'b'
    rescue Exception => e
        puts 'c'
    ensure
        puts 'd'
    end
    puts 'e'
end
```

where:

- `test` is a controller in Ruby on Rails
- `authenticate_user!` is a function from the devise Ruby library
- the result of accessing this is a HTTP 401

prints:

```
a
d
```

To me, this indicates that `authenticate_user!` has thrown some kind of exception, but we weren't able to catch it. How is this possible?

I also tried the following rescue blocks:

```
rescue Object => e
    puts 'c'
rescue e
    puts 'c'
rescue 
    puts 'c'
```

Comment: `Exception` is the highest class in the hierarchy of exceptions. Anything not in this class is not an exception.

Comment: It is strange. `e` should be printed regardless of the exception.

Comment: But I also tried catching Object, which is the highest class, but that was the same result.

Comment: The fact that 'e' wasn't printed is what has led me to believe it is an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of error-handling flow in Ruby.

The most commonly used, and most flexible is `begin...rescue`

There is also `throw` and `catch`, which is much more lightweight. Some of the Rack libraries use this mechanism.

Most importantly, and sometimes annoyingly, the mechanisms are separate, and if a library uses `throw...catch` for program flow, you cannot intercept the messages using `begin...rescue`, therefore a `rescue Exception` block will not get executed.

In general you should not try and intercept third-party `throw`/`catch`, unless documentation suggests that you can. That is because the library will probably have modified `env` to set an error message/state. Instead, look for an equivalent method that does not work with Rack errors, but returns `true` or `false` for the conditions you are checking. For instance, perhaps the method `user_signed_in?` would be better.

---

Example of how catch works in Ruby:

```
puts 'a'
x = catch(:mysymbol) do
    puts 'b'
    throw :mysymbol, 'world'
    puts 'c'
end
puts "hello #{x}"
```

prints

```
a
b
hello world
```

Comment: Cool.  So how would I modify my code to catch it? (i.e. I don't know what is being thrown, so to debug I wanted to catch it to see what it is)

Comment: If what Neil suggests is the case with your library, then there should be a certain **label** (usually a symbol) that is `throw`-n. You need to figure that out, and `catch` that. You need to look into the source to do that.

Comment: @TomG: sawa is correct. I do not think there is a way to generically catch a message, you need to know the correct label. It may not be advisable to intercept a library's `throw`/`catch` mechanism (other rack environment may have been set) - you should check instead to see if there is an equivalent to `authenticate_user!` that gives you a `true` or `false` instead of managing program flow.

Comment: Great, thanks Neil.  I've tested it and the catch works (catching symbol ':warden').  I've added that to your answer.  Hope that's ok.

Comment: @TomG: Sorry rejected that. The `catch` was in the wrong place to do anything - perhaps I saw an earlier/incomplete version?

Comment: @TomG: I'm happy to add your code to the answer, but won't be able to verify that it works. Could you re-submit an edit, or perhaps link a gist?

Comment: @NeilSlater I've resubmitted a simpler example that you can check works